# what is the Volume and BaseVolume reported from bittrex API?

Tags: exchanges, api, bittrex

For example in https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries or if you subscribe to the ws feed you get sent the following type thing.

```
{
  "MarketName": "BTC-ANS",
  "High": 0.0031,
  "Low": 0.00248777,
  "Volume": 1141826.57957173,
  "Last": 0.00295907,
  "BaseVolume": 3316.06464979,
  "TimeStamp": "2017-08-02T10:54:39.273",
  "Bid": 0.00295907,
  "Ask": 0.00296061,
  "OpenBuyOrders": 2439,
  "OpenSellOrders": 6856,
  "PrevDay": 0.00259698,
  "Created": "2016-10-26T01:28:31.96"
}
```

What does `volume` and `BaseVolume` equal though.. volume traded over last 24h ? The value goes up and down so bit confused. Anyone know ?

If you look at a coin here https://bittrex.com/Market/Index?MarketName=BTC-DGB the `v` which i assume is volume always seems to be really low.

Comment: what is prevday ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Volume is the amount traded in that altcoin over the past 24 hours.

In the case of BTC-DGB, this is the amount of DGB that has been traded in 24 hours.

> BaseVolume is the total value traded in the base currency, for example Bitcoin.

Volume increases regardless if it is a buy or sell order.

To find the overall volume you can go to https://coinmarketcap.com.

Comment: "Volume increases regardless if it is a buy or sell order." wow, so do you basically say that the same person can buy and sell back and forth and volume will still rise?

Comment: @jayarjo yes, this is called wash trading. on some exchanges you can even buy from your own sell orders. However, this is mostly pointless and will still cost you transaction fees