# Bittrex API OpenBuyOrders OpenSellOrders - what do they actually show?

Tags: api, bittrex, volume

e.g. https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-bcc

shows:

**{..."OpenBuyOrders":1557,"OpenSellOrders":13944,...}**

What do these numbers refer to since they do not match the BTC or BCC bid and ask volume values on the bittrex screen when looking at this pair.

Any ideas what these two values are showing? I need to know the total number of bid and ask BTC volumes via the API calls? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bittrex API documentation](https://bittrex.com/home/api) doesn't divulge many details but I expect those two values would be all outstanding (open) buy and sell offers, not just for that day.

You may need to contact Bittrex for further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, Willtech. Do you specifically mean the number of outstanding (open) buy and sell orders rather than referring to the currency value?

Comment: What would be useful is the OpenBuyOrders_Base value i.e. the BTC or other CCY amount! The number of orders is not useful and doesnt give the right indication of volume

Comment: This Q & A may help further: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57512/what-is-the-volume-and-basevolume-reported-from-bittrex-api